# Como acessar agenda no android e selecionar contato

Tags: android

Quero fazer minha aplicação acessar a agenda do sistema e trazer um contato para salvar os dados em banco (SQlite).

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt Paulo. Seria legal se vc nos mostrasse o que vc já fez, assim a comunidade pode lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: Paulo, em geral são usadas `Intents` para isso, chegou a tentar algo assim?

Comment: ja utilizo essa intent para acessar a agenda:                                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/contacts/");
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
                startActivity(i);

Comment: agr preciso retornar os dados do contato selecionado

Answer (score 3):

Você está fazendo certo, é preciso utilizar uma Intent para acessar a aplicação de *Agenda de Contatos* do Android. O que falta fazer é acessar os contatos da Agenda e retorná-los.

Primeiramente, você deve ter uma classe de `MeuContato` que será onde você irá "salvar" o contato retornado da agenda. Suponha que você queira pegar todos os contatos da agenda com seus respectivos nomes. Nesse caso, você poderia usar o seguinte código:

```
public ArrayList<MeuContato> pegarContatos(){

    ArrayList<MeuContato> listaDeContatos = new ArrayList<>();

    Uri agenda = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = getContenResolver.query(agenda,null,null,null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        /* Pegue mais informações de acordo com os atributos da sua classe MeuContato */

        MeuContato contato = new MeuContato(nome);

        listaDeContatos.add(contato);
    }

    cursor.close();

    return listaDeContatos;
}
```

Em seguida,basta você percorrer a lista de contatos retornada e ir salvando cada contato no seu banco de dados.

*OBS.:* O segundo parâmetro do método `getContenResolver.query()` pode ser substituido por uma query, por exemplo, se você quiser retornar apenas os contatos que possuem um número de telefone associado, substitua o segundo parâmetro do método por `ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1"`

Para mais informações: [Contacs Contract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)